# I need help conceptualizing my GUI implementation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make a game where I can have an n number of players.

problem is how can I make a `JFrame` for each player if I don't know the number?

Originally I planned on making multiple frames, panels and `JButton` components and their action listener for say 5 players, then limit the users to only have 5 players to play with. But still, that would mean making 5 options buttons for 5 players so 25 buttons and 5 frames and that seems really ridiculous.

I was wondering if there was a way to make this easy? I am really new to java and especially the GUI part. I want to use Swing, not JavaFX.

This is how I want to implement my players:

```
ArrayList<Players> players = new ArrayList();
gamePanel(players);
```

Normally I would do

```
JFrame f = new JFrame(playerName);
```

but how can I make multiple frames with a number of player objects? Or maybe just one frame that switches back and forth between the player objects based on what buttons they have pressed? Based on some win condition I also want to remove the frames associated with the players, and then get more user input via button clicks, until there is only one user in the `ArrayList`. I am not sure how to go about all of this, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will the amount of players change during the game or stay fixed?

Comment: @MDK the players will be removed based on some win condition. Say we have 5 players, 2 players score 1 the other scoring 3 or higher. everyone with the lowest score will be removed. So the players with 1 will be removed and game continues with these 3players until only one player is in the ArrayList.

Comment: You can create an array of JFrames, then iterate over the array N times where N is the number of players, instantiating a JFrame each time.

Comment: @byxor what about the buttons inside the frame? Can I reuse the same buttons in the different frames? Ex. B1 =1 to b5=5 each frame will have these 5 buttons and the players associated with their frame will click this button and set it to themselves. Do i have to make 25 different buttons or can I reuse the first 5 in each frame?

Comment: Whether or not you can reuse the buttons depends on how you've structured the code and how your program should work. We can't answer that for you unfortunately

Comment: As an aside .. doesn't each player need a keyboard / mouse to control their actions in the game? Sounds like you need as many computers as there are players, each showing a single `JFrame` for that player. Sockets can help coordinate the game play between the computers.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way would be to store your `JFrame` objects in a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). This way you can add a new `JFrame` associated with a player:

```
HashMap<Player, JFrame> frames = new HashMap<>();
for (Player player : players) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(player.getName());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // additional setup, creating buttons for the frame, ...
    frames.put(player, frame);
}
```

after that you can easily access each frame by calling `frames.get(player);`, for example `frames.get(players.get(0)).dispose();` to shut down the frame associated with the first player and afterwards `frames.remove(players.get(0))` to delete the mapping.

You can also easily iterate over all frames, for example

```
for (JFrame frame : frames.values()) {
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

For further reading about structuring GUIs I recommend to have a look at the Model-View-Controller pattern. That pattern is very useful to organize how the model (in your case the players) interact with the view (in your case the JFrames).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have not seen hash map yet so I will try this out and hopefully learn on the way. I hope you don't mind if i have other questions regarding this implementation after i tired it out. Again thank you!